# Prefetch some data before initialization in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

As another app I am developing I need to prefetch the users permissions in order to display some menus and access certain routes (this permissions will only be preserved on runtime). The first approach I thought on was to use a resolver, but it seems that I would have to implement it in every parent route I add to the app. What would be the best way to do this?

I tried searching the docs for something related but I couldn't find it.

Comment: What backend you are using?

Comment: @SK. node.js with express and MongoDB.

Comment: You can use a parent route with an empty path and no component, and put the guard there. Or you can use *ngIf inside your app component template to only display something once the user permissions are known.

Comment: I tried, but I have different routing modules, so I would have to apply the same guard to every route. @JBNizet

Comment: You could use the APP_INITIALIZER token to get the data before initializing your application

Comment: I'll try it right away, thank you so much :). Just another question It seems in Angular 6 is experimental(but it is not in Angular 5) does it mean that are they going to remove it? @David

Comment: That's weird. It's been around since angular 2, so it should not be experimental anymore. If they were going to remove it, they'd tag is as deprecated